# Block packets with specific size over specific protocol

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I need to block all packets which are being send over QUAKE2 protocol and are 126 bytes in size.
I couldn't find a way how to achieve this, how can this be done?

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: What have you learned from your research? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quake II uses UDP port 27910. If you're on Linux you can use iptables to drop any udp packet matching 126 bytes in size for destination port 27910.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -p udp --destination-port 27910 -m length --length 126:126 -j DROP
```